# If $\int_1^e \frac{x^4\ln x+2}{x^3\ln x+x}dx=\frac{e^2+a}{b}-\ln(e^2+1)$, where a and b are positive integers. Then the value of a+b is?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> If $\displaystyle \int_1^e \dfrac{x^4\ln x+2}{x^3\ln x+x}dx=\dfrac{e^2+a}{b}-\ln(e^2+1)$, where a and b are positive integers. Find the value of a+b.

I have tried substituting $\ln x$ for $t$ but no success so far. I cannot think of any other handy substitution. Can anyone guide me, even a hint will do.

Comment: Have you tried integrating by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=e^t$, then given integral becomes 
$$I(x)=\int \frac{2+te^{4t}}{1+te^{2t}}dt= \int \frac
{te^{4t}+2+e^{2t}+2te^{2t}-e^{2t}(1+2t)}{1+te^{2t}}dt.$$
$$\Rightarrow I(x)= \int \frac{(e^{2t}+2)(te^{2t}+1)}{(1+te^{2t})}dt-\int \frac{du}{u}, ~\mbox{here}~ u=1+te^{2t}.$$
$$\Rightarrow I(x)= \int (e^{2t}+2)dt -\ln u =\frac{e^{2t}}{2} +2t -\ln (1+te^{2t})$$
$$ I(x)=x^2/2+2\ln x-\ln (1+x^2 \ln x)$$
By putting the limits $x=1$ and $x=e$, we get the definite integral as
$$I=\frac{e^2+3}{2}-\ln(1+e^2).$$
Then $a=3$ and $b=2$, hence $a+b=5.$